# Magento Mass Action URL results in 404

Tags: magento

I know I must be missing something obvious here.. But I just can't see what is missing. I have added a new custom mass action in the customers grid via an observer with the following code:

```
public function addMassActions($observer) {
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'customer')
    {
        $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('tmcustomerapproval/approvals')->getStatuses();
        $block->addItem('tmcustomerapproval', array(
            'label' => 'Set Customer Approval Status',
            'url' => Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/customerapproval/index'),
            'additional'   => array(
                'visibility'    => array(
                    'name'     => 'status',
                    'type'     => 'select',
                    'class'    => 'required-entry',
                    'label'    => Mage::helper('tmcustomerapproval')->__('Status'),
                    'values'   => $statuses
                )
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

This works fine. The action shows up. However upon clicking submit I get the frontend 404. In config.xml I have:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Tweakmag_CustomerApproval after="Mage_Adminhtml">Tweakmag_CustomerApproval</Tweakmag_CustomerApproval>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

and the controller itself is stored in: /app/code/community/Tweakmag/CustomerApproval/controllers/Customerapproval.php

and has the following code:

```
class Tweakmag_CustomerApproval_CustomerapprovalController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
```

{

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

}

I have cleared cache, logged in / out etc. Help, very much appreciated so I can continue to enjoy the weekend :)
Thanks
Adam

Comment: SOLVED! and as suspected. Was a simple error. controller filename was incorrect. Should be CustomerapprovalController.php

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of 404 routes in Magento is a misnamed controller file.  Debugging code in the `_validateControllerClassName` method `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php` is the best way to see which controller file Magento is trying to manually autoload, which will usually point to how your file is named incorrectly.